# How to install Debian 11 on WSL Manually ? I am trying to download it from from Microsoft store but by default it's downloading Debian 12 version

Tags: linux, debian, wsl-2

I am using Windows 10 and trying to download Debian 11 (Bullseye) in my WSL environment.
I am able to download Debian from Microsoft store, but by default, it's installing Debian 12 only.
I also tried with Manually download link to download it using Appx bundle, but it also gave me Debian 12 package only. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions)

Is there any way to download and install Debian 11 Appx bundle or any other alternative to install Debian 11 on my WSL environment?

[image]

I tried with to install it with the below link. but got below error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro#import-the-tar-file-into-wsl
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro#import-the-tar-file-into-wsl

Comment: i tried this but no luck :(

Comment: Can you elaborate on how did you try, and what was the problem ?

Comment: yes @Philippe .. on step 4 while applying wsl -d.. i am getting error.. i have updated the question.

Comment: @Tejas did you ever get this figured out? I need the same thing. Where did you find a .tar file for Debian? I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: Importing a docker image worked for me. And because it took me a while to gather the necessary steps, I'll list them here. As a note, I ran the docker commands from within another Linux distro in WSL, simply because I found it easier to handle there than on Windows. I don't believe this changes anything, though.

I looked for Debian images [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/tags?page=1&name=bullse), and decided on bullseye-slim:

`docker pull debian:bullseye-slim`

Once

`docker run debian:bullseye-slim`

gets this image running its container ID can be found from a different terminal via

`docker container ls` or `docker ps`

(or, if you are scripting this step, via the command provided in the [Microsoft docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro#export-the-tar-from-a-container)).

`docker export CURRENT_ID > debian11.tar`

created a .tar file from the still running image.

Now calling

`wsl --import Debian11 .\WSLStorage\Debian11\ .\debian11.tar`

from the Windows Powershell successfully imported it to the pre-existing folder `.\WSLStorage\Debian11\`.

Comment: Do you run that last command from within a WSL distro? I'm getting "-bash: wsl: command not found"

Comment: No, I called this last command from the Windows powershell. WSL stands for "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and does not exist on Linux. Sorry, my answer was unclear on that. I updated it.